# WPF is it possible to update a listbox without using binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I know OnPropertyChanged and OnCollectionChanged can be used to update a binding to an itemssource, but I want to try doing things manually for once.

I don't want to go through the trouble of data virtualization and it seems like it would be easier to just manually change what i want to be displayed on the screen.

however, if I add items to the listbox manually, the listbox doesn't update. I have almost no experience doing anything in WPF without binding, so I'm not even certain the support exists.

Is there a way to add items and then give the listbox an update command? or is the listbox supposed to automatically update when its items are changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using code behind you should just be able to do this:

```
 ListBoxItem item = new ListBoxItem();
 item.Content = "Example Text";

 listBox.Items.Add(item);
```

If you're using a view model you just need to make sure you call `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the `ObservableCollection` the `listbox` is bound to after adding an item.

Comment: thanks. I think you're right. For some reason that is not working in my main project, even though i just got it to work in a test project.

Comment: If you post the code that's not working I might be able to see why.

Comment: i got it. easy to figure out now. just accidentally trying to bind the wrong item.